# How to build two elf using different compiler options in one Makefile?

Tags: gcc, makefile

Suppose I hava a make file like this. I can get normal build through `make` and get a debug build through `make debug`. But how to write a target so that I can get both normal build and debug build in one command like `make both`?

```
DST := /data/result
debug: CFLAGS += -DDEBUG -g
debug: DST = /some/dir
target: src1.c src2.c
    gcc -bla -bla -o target
    cp target $(DST)
debug: target
```

My final solution is as follows：

```
DST := /data/result
debug: CFLAGS += -DDEBUG -g
debug: DST = /some/dir
target: src1.c src2.c
    gcc -bla -bla -o target
    cp target $(DST)
debug: target

both:
    make debug && make clean && make all
```

Comment: If you `make debug`, it produces `/some/dir/target`, but what if you `make`? What is the default value of `DST`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NORMAL := /data/result/target
DEBUG := /some/dir/target

$(NORMAL) $(DEBUG): src1.c src2.c
    gcc -bla -bla $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

debug: $(DEBUG)
$(DEBUG): CFLAGS += -DDEBUG -g

both: $(NORMAL) $(DEBUG)
```

Comment: Actually your answer is not quite I want because there are multiple target directories in my situation. Finally I let make do the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
both : target debug

target debug : src1.c src2.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

debug : CFLAGS += -g
```